# Don't run "make test" as a part of Travis CI?

Tags: c, travis-ci

I found that a single-line `language: c` .travis.yml file basically does all I need, with the exception that I don't want `make test` to happen. Is there a way I could make Travis just run `./configure && make`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried overriding the default test script as described in: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/c#Default-Test-Script?

Something like:

```
script:
  ./configure && make
```